# Splitting string value c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to know about how to splitting a value in string format in to two parts. Here in my asp application I'm parsing string value from view to controller.

And then I want to split the whole value in to two parts.

Example like: Most of the times value firest two letters could be TEXT value (like "PO" , "SS" , "GS" ) and the rest of the others are numbers (SS235452).

The length of the numbers cannot declare, since it generates randomly. So Want to split it from the begining of the string value. Need a help for that.

My current code is

```
string approvalnumber = approvalCheck.ApprovalNumber.ToUpper();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please specify your exact criteria - you say "most of the time" but what about the other times? Are you trying to split letters and numbers from a string where "all the letters" would be the first item and "all the numbers" would be the second? If so regex is one way to do it...

Comment: @Charleh I mean the format of the input is ```TextTextNumNumNumNum``` like wise. first two letters are text and others are numbers. But There is no static length. First two letters are text and rest of the others are numbers

Comment: have you tried approvalnumber.Substring(2);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you already mentioned that first part will have 2 letters and it's only second part which is varying, you can use Substring Method of String as shown below.

```
        var textPart = input.Substring(0,2);
        var numPart = input.Substring(2);
```

The first line fetches 2 characters from starting index zero and the second statement fetches all characters from index 2. You can cast the second part to a number if required.

Please note that the second parameter of Substring is not mentioned in second line. This parameter is for length and if nothing is mentioned it fetches till end of string.

Comment: Hi. It's so simple code and thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could try using regex to extract alpha, numbers from the string.

This javascript function returns only numbers from the input string.

```
function getNumbers(input) {
            return input.match(/[0-9]+/g);
}
```

Comment: But in this particular case (it's known that there are exactly two letters), a substring is easier

Comment: @amitpatole Thanks for the solution. I'll try this also

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a RegExp. Considering the fact that you indicate ASP-NET-4 I assume you can't use tuples, `out var` etc. so it'd go as follows:

```cs
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using FluentAssertions;
using Xunit;

namespace Playground
{
    public class Playground
    {
        public struct ProjectCodeMatch
        {
            public string Code { get; set; }

            public int? Number { get; set; }
        }

        [Theory]
        [InlineData("ABCDEFG123", "ABCDEFG", 123)]
        [InlineData("123456", "", 123456)]
        [InlineData("ABCDEFG", "ABCDEFG", null)]
        [InlineData("ab123", "AB", 123)]
        public void Split_Works(string input, string expectedCode, int? expectedNumber)
        {
            ProjectCodeMatch result;
            var didParse = TryParse(input, out result);

            didParse.Should().BeTrue();
            result.Code.Should().Be(expectedCode);
            result.Number.Should().Be(expectedNumber);
        }

        private static bool TryParse(string input, out ProjectCodeMatch result)
        {
            /*
             * A word on this RegExp:
             * ^ - the match must happen at the beginning of the string (nothing before that)
             * (?<Code>[a-zA-Z]+) - grab any number of letters and name this part the "Code" group
             * (?<Number>\d+) - grab any number of numbers and name this part the Number group
             * {0,1} this group must occur at most 1 time
             * $ - the match must end at the end of the string (nothing after that)
             */
            var regex = new Regex(@"^(?<Code>[a-zA-Z]+){0,1}(?<Number>\d+){0,1}$");

            var match = regex.Match(input);

            if (!match.Success)
            {
                result = default;
                return false;
            }

            int number;
            var isNumber = int.TryParse(match.Groups["Number"].Value, out number);

            result = new ProjectCodeMatch
            {
                Code = match.Groups["Code"].Value.ToUpper(),
                Number = isNumber ? number : null
            };
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A linq answer:

```
string d = "PO1232131";
string.Join("",d.TakeWhile(a => Char.IsLetter(a)))
```